# Switch&Case not working correctly to launch activities in a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Rookie developer here so sorry for this simple question. I´m using a listView to launch activities. Don´t know why if I use ***switch and case*** is not working correctly. It opens the new activity but when I press Android Back Button on my device I go through all the activities until arrive the one where it was launched. If I use ***if*** option, works perfectly. I will put the code which is working for me and which it isn´t.
This below is working fine

```
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long id) {

            if(position==0){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reetiquetado.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);}

            if(position==1){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChequeoStock.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);}

            if(position==2){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EntradaManual.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);}
```

This below is not working correctly. When I press one on my options, it goes to a different activity and when I press Back Button, I don´t see the Activity who launch it

```
   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long id) {
         switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, Reetiquetado.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                case 1:
                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, ChequeoStock.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent1);

                case 2:
                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, EntradaManual.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent2);
            }
             }
          };
```

Comment: you are missing `break;` in the end of each `case`

Comment: And you should have an `default:` option in each switch statement.

Comment: thanks everybody for your comments, really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `break` after a `case` is found..

Please rewrite your code as follows

```
switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, Reetiquetado.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    break; /***Add a break statement after this case ****/

                case 1:
                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, ChequeoStock.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent1);
                    break; /***Add a break statement after this case ****/

                case 2:
                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(EntradaManual.this, EntradaManual.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent2);
                    break; /***Add a break statement after this case ****/
            }
```

Comment: Oh my god!, I couldn´t be more noob!. Thanks a lot Lal, I should have realised about this mistake.